# How do I get bot to read mention?

Tags: discord.py

If someone mentions me how do I get the bot to read that? like if someone mentions me I want the bot to say something back. How would I do that?

```
@client.event
me = '<@user_id>'
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author.id 
    if message.content == me:
        await message.channel.send('my master will be back shortly')
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `discord.Message.mentions`. It returns a list of `discord.Member` that were mentioned in message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    me = message.guild.get_member(<user id>)
    if me in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send('my master will be back shortly')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

## Reference

- [`discord.Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

Comment: do i have to import anything? i tired it it doesn't seem to work, i put my user id in the <> but the bot doesn't reply.

Comment: Remove the `<>`. You just have to type your id in brackets.

Comment: yes i only wrote the id but it doesnt seem to work